# Highlihtjs + Vuejs + Bootstrap 4: Variable no actualiza en la vista

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

Estoy tratando de renderizar un un card con `navbar` + `hihglightjs` + `Vuejs` pero cuando me cambio de un menu a otro me quita los estilos.

```js
Vue.component("api-code", {
  template:
/*html*/
` 
<div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a :class="activeClass.php"  v-on:click="changeView('php')">PHP</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a :class="activeClass.python"  v-on:click="changeView('python')">Python</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a :class="activeClass.csharp"  v-on:click="changeView('csharp')">C#</a>
                </li>                  
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">                           
                <pre>
                    <code class="php">
                        {{language}}
                    </code>
                </pre>                                                                                              
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
`,
  data() {
return {
  activeClass: {
    php: "nav-link active",
    python: "nav-link",
    csharp: "nav-link",
  },
  language: ` 
  class Hello
  {
    public $name = "php";
  }
  `,
};
  },
  methods: {
changeView(lang) {
  this.language = lang;
  this.show(lang);
  if (lang == "php") {
    console.log("php");
    this.activeClass.php = "nav-link active";
    this.activeClass.python = "nav-link";
    this.activeClass.csharp = "nav-link";
  }

  if (lang == "python") {
    console.log("python");
    this.activeClass.python = "nav-link active";
    this.activeClass.php = "nav-link";
    this.activeClass.csharp = "nav-link";
  }

  if (lang == "csharp") {
    console.log("csharp");
    this.activeClass.csharp = "nav-link active";
    this.activeClass.php = "nav-link";
    this.activeClass.python = "nav-link";
  }
},
show(lang) {
  if (!lang) {
    lang = "php";
  }
  if (lang == "php") {
    this.language = ` 
    class Hello
    {
      public $name = "php";
    }
    `;
    console.log(this.language);
  }
  if (lang == "python") {
    this.language = ` 
    class Hello
    {
      public $name = pyhon;
    }
    `;
    console.log(this.language);
  }
},
  },
});

let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
message: "Hello",
  },
});
/*<div>
    <h1>Highlightjs</h1>
    <pre>
        <code class="php">
            class Hello
            {
                public $name = "Luis";
            }
        </code>
    </pre>
</div>*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@10.2.1/build/styles/default.min.css"
    />
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@10.2.1/build/highlight.min.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.2.1/styles/atom-one-dark.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-Fcqyubi5qOvl+yCwSJ+r7lli+CO1eHXMaugsZrnxuU4DVpLYWXTVoHy55+mCb4VZpMgy7PBhV7IiymC0yu9tkQ=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script>
      hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <api-code></api-code>
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="js/components/NavHeaderComponent.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Básicamente el resultado final que busco obtener es muy parecido a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo

Ya que he buscado algo listo para implementar en Laravel y no consigo nada que remotamente se le parezca.

Comment: Refactoricé el codigo realizando algunos cambios, ahora llamo una función con la que le cambio el valor a la variable que muestro en highlights con el codigo. El codigo lo puedo mejorar aun más pero para efectos de prueba esta bien.

El problema es que a pesar de que la variable cambia de valor en la vista no cambia.

Comment: Se agrega Imagen para ilustrar el resultado final que se busca obtener.